# Discrepant documentation - Slurm profile not working in Snakemake > 8.0

Tags: slurm, snakemake

[Slurm profile for Snakemake](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm) worked as a charm for versions of Snakamake < 8.0. It stoped working since there are few [big changes and renaming](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/migration.html#migrating-to-snakemake-8).
Specifically, newer versions do not seem to detect the flags `cluster-sidecar`, `cluster-cancel`, `cluster` and `cluster-status`. This is unfortunately clashing with the [documentation from Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/additional_features.html#using-cluster-sidecar).

Could someone point me to the new documentation or how to avoid these errors / rename the flags?

I attempted running my code (which runs perfectly with version 7.32.4) and was thrown a Snakemake issue of unrecognized flags.